# How to get a file in pure binary

Tags: javascript, typescript, upload, filereader, antd

I have a file that I upload using [antdUpload](https://ant.design/components/upload/)

The html renderer :

```
    <Upload
        beforeUpload={((file: RcFile, fileList: RcFile[]): boolean => {this.requestUpload(file, (fileList.length || 0 )); return false;})}
    ></Upload>
```

The code part :

```
requestUpload(file: RcFile, nbFile: number): void {
    const r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = (): void => {
        FileHelper.uploadFile({
            filename: file.name,
            filepath: `${this.props.datastoreId}/${this.props.itemId}/${this.props.fieldId}/${file.name}`,
            file: r.result,
            field_id: this.props.fieldId,
            item_id: this.props.itemId || '',
            d_id: this.props.datastoreId || '',
            p_id: this.props.projectId || '',
            display_order: nbFile
        }).subscribe()
    };
    r.readAsArrayBuffer (file);
}
```

So I get an `RcFile` (which just extend the type `file`) from that moment, I don't know what to do to get a raw binary of the file. my API only work with a raw binary, and nothing else. so I need that `file: r.result,` to be a pure binary raw data.

I found other stackoverflow question, but they all say how it should be (using base64 or other) but not how to do it if you have no other option to change it.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Instead of `r.readAsArrayBuffer`, and you tried `r.readAsBinaryString()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString

Comment: yes, and I can actually see the file (and is not a binary) but how do i convert that binary string to pure binary ?

Also, like I upload a txt, the r.result is the exact content of the txt but not as binarry

Comment: I think a binary string is as close as you get in Javascript land. I'm interested to see other answers though...

Comment: @TJBlackman If I check some upload library like the one I send, by default they upload a pure binary. but I can't find how.

Comment: Must be a `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` then. Can you post a link to the API docs so I can read them? Do some reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: @TJBlackman the link is on the first line of the question

Comment: I was also using this before, it also allow binary upload https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

According to the file-upload tool you linked ([ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)) you should first: "*Ask questions on StackOverflow under the 'ng-file-upload' tag.*" So, add that tag to this post.

Then if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "binary" on the docs, I see this:

```
Upload.http({
  url: '/server/upload/url',
  headers : {
    'Content-Type': file.type
  },
  data: file
})
```

Looks like they're passing a file object as the data, and the w/e the file type is in the header. I haven't tried this though...

Comment: I am not using ng-file-upload... I give you as an exemple. 

What I use is this https://ant.design/components/upload/ which is in the tag, and also in the first line of my Question (if you click you will go to this page)

https://ant.design/components/upload/

Comment: also my question is not how to use them, cause I know how to use their built in http to send data, but I would like to use my service (which is already setup with correct header/ token etc...) , so I would like to know a way to get binary from the File type